# MongoDB Change/Update Subdocument Field

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I currently have a Mongo DB database with one collection ('locations') with one document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5875653b89513c8328416522"),
"name" : "Starcups",
"address" : "125 High Street, Reading, RG6 1PS",
"rating" : 3,
"facilities" : [
    "Hot drinks",
    "Food",
    "Premium wifi"
],
"coords" : [
    -0.9690884,
    51.455041
],
"openingTimes" : [
    {
        "days" : "Monday - Friday",
        "opening" : "7:00am",
        "closing" : "7:00pm",
        "closed" : false
    },
    {
        "days" : "Saturday",
        "opening" : "8:00am",
        "closing" : "5:00pm",
        "closed" : false
    },
    {
        "days" : "Sunday",
        "closed" : true
    }
],
"reviews" : [
    {
        "author" : "Simon Holmes",
        "id" : ObjectId("5875663389513c8328416523"),
        "rating" : 5,
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2013-07-15T23:00:00Z"),
        "reviewText" : "What a great place. I can't say enough good things about it."
    }
]
}
```

I need to alter the field "id" (part of the subdocument reviews) to "_id". I have tried, using other similar examples on StackExchange, the following code to no avail:

```
db.locations.update({}, {$rename:{"reviews.id":"reviews._id"}}, false, true);
```

But I receive the following error:

```
WriteResult({
"nMatched" : 0,
"nUpserted" : 0,
"nModified" : 0,
"writeError" : {
    "code" : 16837,
    "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (reviews of reviews.id) to traverse the element ({reviews: [ { author: \"Simon Holmes\", id: ObjectId('5875663389513c8328416523'), rating: 5.0, timestamp: new Date(1373929200000), reviewText: \"What a great place. I can't say enough good things about it.\" } ]})"
}
})
```

I get the same error when I try to alter any other field. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Update:

This seems to be a problem assessing the subdocument field as the following code executes fine:

```
db.locations.update({}, {$rename:{"name":"names"}}, false, true);
```

I have also tried searching through the relevant documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/

Answer (score 0):

That's because Reviews is an `Array`

You cannot `$rename` to do that , instead you need to $set the new name and $unset the old one

Comment: Thanks - this is because of the [ ] enclosing the different values within review right? Also as I am utilising this data from elsewhere is there any reason why an array, in this instance, would be more useful than an object? There may well be more than one review attached to each "location" entry. Could that be the reason?